# Where is the Benelli R1 made?

Tags: hunting, guns

I might be in the market for a new Benelli R1. But I can't seem to get a straight answer on where it is made. Obviously, I know that Benelli is a Beretta company and the Benelli address is listed in MD (not far from Accokeek). But is the Benelli R1 made in the US or is it made in Italy, or somewhere else? To be clear, I am **specifically** interested in the R1 - I know that manufacturers sometimes make different arms in different parts of the world.

Comment: Hunting rifles are almost by definition related to TGO.  If anyone would like to discuss that as a community, please create a topic in meta:  http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9):

Benelli's plant is in Urbino (Italy). It's the only manufacturing site where the final products (so, of course also the R1) are assembled and the final QA takes place.

https://goo.gl/maps/LvToPLAcnzJ2

*So, you don't have to be afraid that it's manufactured in the US or something ;P*

Comment: I confirm this.  I emailed them yesterday and they emailed back.

Comment: Why would it matter if it was made in the US?

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Was just joking. Doesn't matter.